# Results displaying one at a time with a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, animation

I have the following code that shuffles a selection I have in my database. Rather than having the results display all at one, I want to display a result one at a time with a delay between the results.

ie:

If I have 10 items in my database, I want one item to display, then a 3 second delay, then the second item to display, then a 3 second result, all the way until the last item (#10). Then possibly some sort of animation to it, like flying into the screen or the look of an item coming from a bag or something. (think picking a numbered order from 10 out of a bag).

I have been told that setInterval() could be an approach, but I have no idea how I could make this work with my code or if that is even the right approach.

How could I do this?

Here is how I shuffle the db results.

```
<form method="post"> 
<?php    
    foreach ($array as $result) { 
        $shuffle_firstname = htmlentities($result['firstname']); 
        $shuffle_lastname = htmlentities($result['lastname']); 
        $shuffle_id = htmlentities($result['id']); 
        $shuffle_username = htmlentities($result['username']); 
        $shuffle_email = htmlentities($result['email']); 
?> 
        <div class="shuffle_results"><?php echo $shuffle_firstname . ' ' . $shuffle_lastname; ?></div> 
        <input type="hidden" name="firstname[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_firstname; ?>"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="lastname[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_lastname; ?>"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_id; ?>"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="username[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_username; ?>"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="email[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_email; ?>"> 
    <?php 
    } 
?>   
         <input type="submit" value="Finalize Draft Order" name="insert"> 
    </form>
```

UPDATE:

HTML File

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `group` = 3");

echo 'Users to be given draft order: <br>';
$array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $array[] = $row;
    echo $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'] . '<br>';
}
?>
<form method="POST" name="form">
<input type="submit" value="Create Draft Order" name="shuffle">
```

```
Shuffled results: <br>
<div id="results"></div>
<form method="post">

     <input type="submit" value="Finalize Draft Order" name="insert">
</form>
<img id='paperBag' src="http://www.thecuriouscaterpillar.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/a/bag_to_white.jpg" width="200px" />
//Test Shuffle
var displayResults = function(data){
    var i = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){ 
    if( i <= data.length){ 
    console.log( data[i] ); 
    //i++; 
            $('#results').append('<div class="result" style="display:none;">' +
                        '<div class="shuffle_results">' + data[i].firstname + ' ' + data[i].lastname + '</div>' + 
                        '<input type="hidden" name="firstname[]" value="' + data[i].firstname + '">' +
                        '<input type="hidden" name="lastname[]" value="' + data[i].lastname + '">' +
                        '<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="' + data[i].id + '">' +
                        '<input type="hidden" name="username[]" value="' + data[i].username + '">' +
                        '<input type="hidden" name="email[]" value="' + data[i].email + '">' +
                    '</div>');
            $('.result').fadeIn(200);
            i++;
       } else { 
    clearInterval(interval); 
    } 
    }, 3000); 
    };
$(function(){  
    $('form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
       $.post('shuffle_results.php', function(data){ 
        var o = $.parseJSON(data); 
        displayResults(o); 
        });
        });
    });
//End test shuffle
```

PHP file

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `group` = 3");
$array = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $array[] = $row;

    if (isset($_POST['shuffle'])) {
    shuffle($array);
    }
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Comment: Are you using ajax to return the whole of the html doc?

Comment: As of now, this is all in PHP, unless it would be better to make an AJAX call for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/bahut607/): This is just a test using faux data in the fiddle. Is this close to what you are looking for?

**Client** (using ctwheels's CSS)

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Shuffle" name="shuffle">
</form>
<div id="#results"></div>

<script>
var displayResults = function(data){
    var i = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        if( i <= data.length){
            $('#results').append('<div class="result" style="display:none;">' +
                        '<div class="shuffle_results">' + data[i].firstname + ' ' + data[i].lastname + '</div>' + 
                        '<input type="hidden" name="firstname[]" value="' + data[i].firstname + '">' +
                        '<input type="hidden" name="lastname[]" value="' + data[i].lastname + '">' +
                        '<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="' + data[i].id + '">' +
                        '<input type="hidden" name="username[]" value="' + data[i].username + '">' +
                        '<input type="hidden" name="email[]" value="' + data[i].email + '">' +
                    '</div>');
            var $this = $('.shuffle_results:last');
            $this.show().animate({
                'left': 0 + 'px',
                'bottom': $(document).height() - (lineheight * array.length) + 'px'
            }, {
                duration: time
            });
            i++;
        } else {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 3000);
};
$(function(){  
    $('form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.getJSON('path-to-your-script.php', function(data){
            displayResults(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**Server**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `group` = 3");
$array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $array[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Comment: This one will freeze the execution for 3 seconds. So this code won't work for him. He want the client side to show the result one at a time using ajax i think so @wrxsti

Comment: @JijoJohn I see, I think I misunderstood the question. Will update answer to reflect. Thanks.

Comment: It kind of works? It delays the output from appearing, but I don't think it will allow me to do any sort of animation to it once. Like Jijo John said, this is for the client side purpose.

Comment: Yes, if you want the animations and what not, ajax may be better for this. I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: @Paul can you var_dump($array) for me so I can get an idea of the data format coming to the client if you were to do ajax?

Comment: Here you are ... `array(4) { [0]=> array(10) { ["id"]=> string(2) "43" ["firstname"]=> string(3) "boo" ["lastname"]=> string(3) "boo" ["email"]=> string(17) "gfdg" ["phone_number"]=>'

Comment: ' ["username"]=> string(4) "boop" ["password"]=> string(64) "5528a221f587686ab2b2b297e813d8b38f623b9c4ca72b5af60443d3ef943967" ["salt"]=> string(32) "a��Ώ�P���ͷO�X6D�<�2%Q'�s�ep" ["joined"]=> string(19) "2015-07-13 07:55:24" ["group"]=> string(1) "3" } [1]=> array(10) { ["id"]=> string(2) "44" ["firstname"]=> string(3) "boo" ["lastname"]=> string(3) "boo" ["email"]=> string(17) "gfdgd" ["phone_number"]=> string(12) "031015156161" ["username"]=> string(7) "boopbfd" ["password"]=> string(64) "ec68a7fb45f147ca4977ed0cdc087bceb337f2b0dffdab38c0e8f74ccb46'

Comment: I'm basically pulling the firstname, lastname, email, username. However, I am only displaying(outputting)the first and last name.

Comment: @Paul - This setup is assuming you have a client that will make a request to a script on the server and wait for results from the server. You can certainly make this work with a form, but you will need to use jQuery to .preventDefault() the default actions of form submission, and tell it to instead make an ajax request.

Comment: How could I do that? I have never made an AJAX call that got the info from the php file. I have always sent info to my php file to do an INSERT query. I am going to add more code to show what I am trying to do. I am doing all of this to get users order.

Comment: @Paul - I put an example above, but yes more information is always helpful :)

Comment: I do not need anything for the insert form. Only this one `<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Shuffle" name="shuffle">
</form>`

Comment: @Paul - Updated the answer to show one way you could do this with ajax. There are definitely different methods, but this is a common ajax setup. Separating you server and client scripts entirely also helps a lot with project organization.

Comment: Do I have to give the form or input an id so that the data can be found or the form submit will trigger something?

Comment: It is typically a good idea to give your form an ID or a NAME. In the example I haven't and just used $('form') as an easy example.

Comment: It's not working at all for me. I will update my question to show you how I am trying to do it.

Comment: I don't see your <script> tags. Also did you add the jQuery library? Also what console error are you getting?

Comment: I'm using these libraries `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` .... No errors in the console. whenever I click the 'Create Draft Order' button, nothing happens.

Comment: Okay cool, when you click Create Draft Order, do you get anything in your network tab? Does it even make a call to the server?

Comment: Yes, it is making the call to my shuffle_results.php file

Comment: Does it return results? In the response tab of the network tab?

Comment: Where exactly is the response tab in the network tab?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85211/discussion-between-paul-and-wrxsti).

Comment: Not at my computer give me 5 minutes and I will hop into chat.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is by hiding all the results using CSS and then one by one show the values and animate using jQuery and CSS animate.

The code below hides all the items in `shuffle_results` by default (in CSS).
Then the jQuery iterates through each item in that class and shows the element, then animates its `left` and `bottom` properties to give it the correct positioning. The duration is set with `time`.

The rotation animations are made with CSS keyframes.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/zwovhkvh/)

**JS**

```
var time = 3000;
var lineheight = 24;
var angle = 90;
$('.shuffle_results').each(function (i) {
    var i = i;
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $this.show()
            .animate({
            'left': 0 + 'px',
                'bottom': $(document).height() - (lineheight * (i + 1)) + 'px'
        }, {
            duration: time,
            queue: false
        });
    }, time * i);
});
```

**CSS**

```
.shuffle_results {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:70px;
    bottom:100px;
    z-index:-1;
    -webkit-animation:spin 3s linear;
    -moz-animation:spin 3s linear;
    animation:spin 3s linear;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(110deg);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(110deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(110deg);
        transform:rotate(110deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
}
#paperBag {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shuffle_results">Michael Jackson</div>
<div class="shuffle_results">Bob Saget</div>
<div class="shuffle_results">Indiana Jones</div>
<div class="shuffle_results">Elmo</div>
<div class="shuffle_results">Elmer J. Fudd</div>
<img id='paperBag' src="http://www.thecuriouscaterpillar.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/a/bag_to_white.jpg" width="200px" />
```

---

**EDIT**

To use this with *AJAX*, you can do something like the following for **JS**

```
var time = 3000;
var lineheight = 24;
var angle = 90;
var array = ["Michael Jackson", "Bob Saget", "Indiana Jones", "Elmo", "Elmer J. Fudd"]; //For testing purposes. Shows how it adds one item at a time. This 'mimicks' your AJAX script
var i=0;
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    j=i;
    i++;
    if(array.length<=i) window.clearInterval(interval);
    // Where array.length is the count returned from PHP (or you can return a boolean value and check if it's true or false. Something like this:
    //if(clearInt === true)
    //{
    //    window.clearInterval(interval);
    //}
    //else
    //{
    //    Do stuff below
    $('#paperBag').before("<div class='shuffle_results'>"+array[j]+"</div>");
    // Where array[j] represents the value returned from ajax
    var $this = $('.shuffle_results:last');
    $this.show()
        .animate({
        'left': 0 + 'px',
            'bottom': $(document).height() - (lineheight * (j + 1)) + 'px'
    }, {
        duration: time
    });
}, time);
```

So you should have something similar to this: (note that this is untested - feel free to edit this answer if you encounter any bugs from it). To prevent duplicate results you can send the array from your JS function to your PHP function and subtract one array from the other to get the remaining values (use the database row's unique index and populate the JS array with those values and then subtract an array with all the values in your PHP script from it to get the remaining values. (using `array_diff` perhaps: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
var time = 3000;
var lineheight = 24;
var angle = 90;
var array = [];
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    $getJSON("something.php", {array: array}, function(result)
    {
        if(result.clearInterval === true)
        {
            window.clearInterval(interval);
        }
        else
        {
            array.push(result.firstName+" "+result.lastName);
            $('#paperBag').before("<div class='shuffle_results'>"+result.firstName+" " +result.lastName+"</div>");
            var $this = $('.shuffle_results:last');
            $this.show()
                .animate({
                'left': 0 + 'px',
                    'bottom': $(document).height() - (lineheight * array.length) + 'px'
            }, {
                duration: time
            });
        }
    });
}, time);
```

Comment: Will it do the same with a while loop though?

Comment: Why do you need a while loop? I'm not quite sure I understand what you are asking, a while loop in the place of what?

Comment: @ctwheels - Initially it wasn't an ajax server/client separation. It was all enclosed within one php document. We are setting it up as ajax now. Hope that clears some of the confusion.

Comment: The while loop is for pulling the users from my database. It isn't statis html with names.

Comment: So you have ajax running inside a timer to get the value of the next 'pulled name' and you want to animate once you've received the result from ajax (i.e. in the success function parameter)?

Comment: Well all of a sudden his server has stopped sending results. Trying to troubleshoot that issue at the moment.

Comment: I've added a way to run AJAX with the function. See my edit above. Read the comments as they give more details

Comment: I've also now added a way to run the AJAX (using getJSON). Just pass a JSON object from PHP to the function above

Comment: @ctwheels I updated my question with the current code, is there anyway to make your animation work for that?

Comment: @Paul The code above should work for you. Just use the last JS I added there and change the values for firstName, lastName, etc. and make sure you're passing it a JSON object.